# Python Flask Azure mail daemon options and O365

Tags: python-3.x, flask

[**UPDATE**]

I have implemented the below solution but am running into problems when running as a service due to the manual intervention required from the `print` output.

Any other suggestions for a solution would be most welcome :(

**[ORIGINAL]**

I have been looking for a mail daemon type solution for a flask application. I'd like to integrate with Auzure rather than run a local mail server, so the MS Graph API looked to be a great choice. I then came across [O365](https://github.com/O365/python-o365) which looked to be a perfect solution.

So I setup some testing and it works great, I even tried setting up the 2 step authentication as an option for login identity ([Web app based authentication interface](https://github.com/O365/python-o365#authentication)).  This works but is not something I want for this project. I would just like the flask app to be able to send emails using Azure (app invites, password resets etc, various mail automations). Moving on...

I found the following authentication method to work perectly well and I dont need to handel any tokens and refreshing. However I cant find anything in the docs to suggest I'd be able to authentication this way but not `print()` the URL but redirect the user. Id like to be able to then capture the redirection in a `route` flow.

Have I missed something here?

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('CLIENT-ID', 'CLIENT-SECRET')
account = Account(credentials)
if not account.is_authenticated:
   account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all'])
   print('Authenticated!')

# A URL is printed if not authed, you would then be required to navigate to this URL,
# give consent to the app then paste the returned URL back into the console. 
# I want to try avoid this direct console approach.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

As no one responded to my calls for help, I thought this might be useful to some.

I resolved this by using the two-stage authentication flow and TokenBackendStorage; details are [here](https://github.com/O365/python-o365#different-authentication-interfaces).

I collected Azure App details via a web front-end. It supplies instructions for configuring the application in Azure and captures relevant details to setup token-based access.

My issues were threefold. I wasn't setting permissions correctly (delegate vs application), I wasn't reading the documentation thoroughly enough, so was implementing a mishmash of auth methods.

This will need refining as its currently POC, storage of the token, for instance, should be encrypted either to disk or within a table on the DB and permissions should be set appropriately. Following the principle of least privilege.

Example authentication two-stage flow:

```
@app.route('/mail-config-step-one', methods=['GET'])
def mail_config_step_one():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        scopes = ['message_all']
        try:
            mail_data = db.session.query(mail_conf).one()
        except:
            mail_data = None
            
        if mail_data :
               
            application_id = mail_data.client_id
            application_secret = mail_data.client_s
            web_redirect = mail_data.web_redir
            callback = web_redirect
            credentials = (application_id, application_secret)
            
            token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='./', token_filename='o365_token.txt')
            account = Account(credentials, scopes=scopes, token_backend=token_backend, tenant_id='TENANT ID')
            
            url, state = account.con.get_authorization_url(redirect_uri=callback)
            mail_conf.query.filter_by(id=1).update(dict(auth_s=state))
            print(url)
            db.session.commit()            
            return redirect(url)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))    


@app.route('/mail-config-step-two/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mail_config_step_two():
    
    scopes = ['message_all']
    mail_data = db.session.query(mail_conf).one()
    application_id = mail_data.client_id
    application_secret = mail_data.client_s
    web_redirect = mail_data.web_redir
    credentials = (application_id, application_secret)
    token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='./', token_filename='o365_token.txt')
    account = Account(credentials, scopes=scopes, token_backend=token_backend, tenant_id='TENANT ID')    

    # retreive the state saved in mail-config-step-one
    saved_state = mail_data.auth_s 
    
    # rebuild the redirect_uri used in auth_step_one
    callback = web_redirect
    
    result = account.con.request_token(request.url, state=saved_state, redirect_uri=callback)
    
    # if the result is True, then authentication was successful 
    #  and the auth token is stored in the token backend

    if result:
        flash('MailConfigurationForm: Authentication Was Successful!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('configuration'))
    else:
        logger.error('mail_config_step_two failed: not post request')
        return redirect(url_for('configuration'))
```